# Am I interpreting this basic diode question correctly?

Tags: diodes, ideal

I am doing a question related to diodes from Sedra Smith Micro electronics and here is the question snip:
[image]

[image]

In the second part of the question where it says that if 1mV is being drawn by a load attached to output terminal, so for this I do the following:::

[image]

And for the value of 'I' I use the result that I get in the first part of the question which is 3.81mV. But the answer I am getting is not correct. The correct value of the output voltage in the second part is -22mV. My answer is not the same.
Can someone guide me as to how to do this question thoroughly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be mixing up volts and amps.

Comment: I meant mA in the diagram. Changed it now.

Comment: How are you trying to do it, and what is your answer? I get -23mV-- and *please* fix the "3.81mV"  in your question.

Comment: Watch out.  The answer to part 1 is extremely sensitive to the exact value of Vt you use.  You used Vt = 25 mV.  However, if you use Vt = 25.25 mV, then the answer to part 1 is only 2.93 mA.  Make sure you are using the same values in part 2 as part 1.

Comment: Assuming the emission coefficient is 1, then I get \$V_T\approx 24.897023\:\textrm{mV}\$ in order to get exactly \$-22\:\textrm{mV}\$ as the difference. To the OP: Are you going to show some of your work? Where did that \$3.81\:\textrm{mV}\$ come from, for example?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part ,
Since Vo is 2 V so potential drop across each diode is 2/3 V.
Hence for calculating I we can use Shockley equation.
I = Is (exp^(2e/3KT)- 1).
Because same I flows across each diode.(diodes connected in series).